# Ansible package warning when using sudo

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, ansible, redhat

I was following this [doc](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) to install shiny package in RedHat 7.3. The command provided in the doc is:

```
$ sudo su - \
-c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

In Ansible, I wrote it like this:

```
- name: Installing Shiny Packages
    shell: sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
   #when: install_R|changed
```

I am getting a warning when I run my playbook:

```
TASK [Installing Shiny Packages] ***********************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather
than running sudo

changed: [test]
```

Please let me know how to write this in ansible so that I can avoid the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because of the outdated `sudo` usage from version `1.9`. From the official Ansible documentation.

> Before `1.9` Ansible mostly allowed the use of `sudo` and a limited use of `su` to allow a login/remote user to become a different user and execute tasks, create resources with the 2nd user’s permissions. As of `1.9`, `become` supersedes the old `sudo/su`, while still being backwards compatible.

You can remove it by using the [`become` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) which allows you to 'become' another user, different from the user that logged into the machine (remote user).  You need to set to `true` to activate privilege escalation.

```
name: Installing Shiny Packages
   shell: R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
become: true
```

Comment: How to write this without sudo: `$ sudo su - \
-c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""` ?

Comment: @user182944: not sure could you try `shell: R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"`

Comment: and how can I install multiple R packages from one-shot?